# How to change hours data from 24-hour format to 12-hour format?

Tags: android, datetime, simpledateformat

I'm retrieving hours data for places from a service (Factual).  It comes to me in 24-hour format and I need to display it in 12-hour format.  The data for a specific day comes like this:

```
"sunday\":[[\"12:00\",\"21:30\"]]
```

I can successfully retrieve the hours from the JSON.  Then, using SimpleDateFormat, I can parse the string to a `Date` object.  But, then I can't figure out how to convert them to 12;-hour format so that I can display them as "12:00 - 9:30" or "12:00pm - 9:30pm" rather than "12:00 - 21:30".

How can I go about doing this?  Thanks!

EDIT:

By parsing the string of hours (i.e. "12:00") using `SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");`, I get an error from JSON saying that the value is unparseable. If I use just `SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");`, then there's no error but I can't get things to show up in 12-hour format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the simple date format syntax docs you will find that 'h' is used for 12-hour time and 'a' is used for AM/PM. You will need to extract the two times using substring before putting them through the dateformatters.
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
SimpleDateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("<input format goes here>");
Date d = in.parse(INPUT_DATE_STRING);
SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("<output format goes here>");
String outDate = out.format(d);
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, and I am parsing it as such using this:   SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");  If I use   SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a"); then it tells me that the values I am trying to parse (i.e. 12:00) are in an unparsable format.

Comment: You should be reading in your original date with 1 format, to a date object, and then outputting it to your format with a different formatter. I've updated my answer with the kind of code you should be using.

Comment: You should accept the answer, if it's answered your question!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//Char sequence for a 12 hour format. 
CharSequence DEFAULT_FORMAT_12_HOUR = "hh:mm a";
//Char sequence for a 24 hour format.
CharSequence DEFAULT_FORMAT_24_HOUR = "kk:mm";

//date is the Date object. Look for more functions in format.
DateFormat.format(DEFAULT_FORMAT_12_HOUR, date);
```

Let me know if it works. If you have any issue check the Date you are sending.

```
//This should give you the default time on the device. To show that it works.
DateFormat.format(DEFAULT_FORMAT_12_HOUR, Calendar.getInstance());
```